# How to change the background color of xreader (document viewer)?

Tags: pdf, theme

System: Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya

I want to change my background color of my pdf-reader "xreader".
I don't mean to invert the DinA4-sheets by pressing
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>,
but the background-color behind the pages, which is by default lightgray. 
Working a lot at night makes it really uncomfortable for the eyes, if its shining too bright on the left and right side.

Is there anywhere a configuration file where I can change the background/backdrop color, for example by changing an RGB or HEX color code?

[image: Screenshot of xreader]

Comment: Do you still have the issue? In my laptop the background is dark gray. I am on Linux mint XFCE using Mint-Y-Dark theme on system settings > appearance.